# Can Mathematica do a Double Path Integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I've obtained some analytical results that I'd like to verify numerically by doing a double path integral. I haven't done this before with Mathematica and am unsure if it's possible, I'd like to do the following path integral;

$\int^{x_{a}}_{{x_{b}}} \int^{y_{a}}_{{y_{b}}}\exp \left[ \frac{i}{\hbar} \left( S[x(t)] - S[y(t)] \right) \right]  \exp \left[ \frac{i}{\hbar} \int^{t}_{0}\left( F[x(\tau),y(\tau)] \right)  d\tau \right]  [dx(t)][dy(t)] $

where

$S[x(t)] =  \int^{t}_{0} \left( \dot{x}(\tau) - v[x(\tau)] \right)  d\tau$,

$v[x(\tau)] = x^{2}(\tau)$,

and

$F[x(\tau),y(\tau)] = \left(x(\tau) - y(\tau)\right)\left(\dot{x}(\tau) - \dot{y}(\tau)\right) - \left(x(\tau) - y(\tau)\right)^{2}$

(For context, it's quantum Brownian motion in which a particle is described within a bath of quantum harmonic oscillators)

Is it possible for Mathematica to do such calculations? If so, could someone point me in a direction to begin?